# C++: how do I check if the cin buffer is empty?

Tags: c++, input, cin

How do you check to see if the user didn't input anything at a cin command and simply pressed enter?

Comment: Read a line and count how many characters?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When reading from [std::cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), it's preferable not to use the [stream extraction operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) `>>` as this can have all sorts of nasty side effects.  For example, if you have this code:

```
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
```

And I enter `John Doe`, then the line to read from `cin` will just hold the value `John`, leaving `Doe` behind to be read by some future read operation.  Similarly, if I were to write:

```
int myInteger;
std::cin >> myInteger;
```

And I then type in `John Doe`, then `cin` will enter an error state and will refuse to do any future read operations until you explicitly clear its error state and flush the characters that caused the error.

A better way to do user input is to use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read characters from the keyboard until the user hits enter.  For example:

```
std::string name;
getline(std::cin, name); // getline doesn't need the std:: prefix here because C++ has ADL.
```

[ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) stands for argument-dependent lookup. Now, if I enter `John Doe`, the value of `name` will be `John Doe` and there won't be any data left around in `cin`.  Moreover, this also lets you test if the user just hit enter:

```
std::string name;
getline(std::cin, name);

if (name.empty()) {
    /* ... nothing entered ... */
}
```

The drawback of using this approach is that if you want to read in a formatted data line, an `int` or a `double` you'll have to parse the representation out of the string.  I personally think this is worth it because it gives you a more fine-grained control of what to do if the user enters something invalid and "guards" `cin` from ever entering a fail state.

I teach a C++ programming course, and have [some lecture notes about the streams library](http://www.keithschwarz.com/cs106l/fall2010/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf) that goes into a fair amount of detail about how to read formatted data from `cin` in a safe way (mostly at the end of the chapter).  I'm not sure how useful you'll find this, but in case it's helpful I thought I'd post the link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped me out with a program I'm working on.  I'm putting in this comment because I found something interesting.  I have an if-else statement that checks if the user inputs "y", "n", something else, or nothing at all.  I found that the program won't hit the "nothing at all" case unless I start the if-else with that case.  I'm not sure if that also happened to other people.

Answer (score 4):

cin will not continue with the program unless the user enters at least 1 character (enter doesn't count). If the user doesn't give ANY input, cin will just keep waiting for the user to give input and then press enter.

Comment: Almost true; depends what operation you do with cin.

Comment: @Fred-Nurk - Can you give me an example?

Comment: Getline was mentioned in another answer, but cin.get and cin.ignore are others.

Answer (score -6):

The Simple way >>

```
{
char X=0; //  ASCII( 0 ) means a NULL value
cin>>X;
if(X==0 || X==10) // ASCII( 10 ) means ENTER
cout<<"User din't enter ANYTHING !! ";
}
```

But a simple problem is....

> cin just won't allow you to move further without entering a character

by character here i mean a DIGIT or alphabet or special symbol , not space, enter null etc

Hope this solves your problem, if it doesn't, I'll be glad to help just let me know.

Answer (score -7):

```
int main(){ 
string str[100];
std::cout<<"Hello how are you ? \n";
std::cin>>str;
if(str.length() > 0){
// If input is seen
}
else{
// If input is not seen
}
}
```

Any problem let me know.

Comment: I dont have compiler so I cant check. but thanks for telling me.

Comment: Istreams do not have an extractor for a string pointer (your str is an array of strings).  You can always [use an online compiler to check](http://codepad.org/AMt9sDzN).

Comment: Also, you are allocating 100 strings. You probably meant `char[100]`.

Comment: @Marlon: Hopefully he meant string str;, but with yours or mine, it still has problems.

Comment: Why are you just making stuff up?

Comment: Any problem?  Lots of problems, actually.